# Access data in AWS Lightsail Container

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-lightsail

Months back I made the rushed decision to run a mongo docker instance in a Amazon Lightsail container (not an instance), with no backups, data mounting, etc.

Now I want to access the container and export the data, so I can switch to alternate storage.

I'm new to Lightsail, but having read the docs, it seems there's no option to access the container / run a CLI, only to redeploy or disable the container.

Is it possible to access the container to retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0):

Presume that you can connect your mongodb as usual, you can use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/) to dump data out from your mongodb container.

Comment: But I'm not running a regular Lightsail instance, it's using the Lightsail container service.

Comment: You can connect to you mongodb via shell (eg cli), right? Checkout the new answer.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'm getting a firewall issue when trying to access it, and AWS only lets you configure that for instances, not containers (`connection <monitor> to SOME_IP_ADDRESS closed`)

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, during the lighsail container deployment stage you can add port, after that you can access your container using the provided URL and port that you opened.

Comment: What is the amount of storage offered by the lightsail container service? The pricing page only shows cpu and memory. I have a python api running on lightsail container service. It's POST endpoint receives a file, stored it in temporary folder, processes the file, deletes the file and responds back with processed JSON. I am curious to know what is the disk space capacity of the lightsail container service.